# TypeScript type string of specific characters

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I want to allow a hex string; so the only allowed values would be 0-9a-f. Is there a way in TypeScript to define a type string that only takes certain strings? i.e.

```
// valid
const valid: HexString = '123abc';
// invalid
const invalid: HexString = 'ijk';
```

I know Regex type definitions is a proposal [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579), was wondering if there was a way to achieve this in the meantime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only with "OpaqueTypes" or "Nominal Types" aslong as you have an implementation that can make a string a HexCode the implementation is as follows.

```
export type Opaque<K, T> = T & { __TYPE__: K };
type HexCode = Opaque<string, "HexCode">

const createHexCode = (str: string): HexCode => {
  // implementation that forces string to be hexCode
  return str.toString() as HexCode // casting is needed.
}
const test = createHexCode("#333");
const isAssignableString: string = test; // yes anything that is HexCode is still technically a string.
const isAssignableHexCode: HexCode = "standard string" // error
```

this pattern is also useful for things like PositiveInteger and PasswordHash where you don't want anyone to accidentally assign a plain-string to that value you want to force people to use a function that returns a PasswordHash

Comment: Presumably you want the implementation of `createHexCode()` to throw a runtime error if the passed in string does not match the regex.  Or maybe `createHexCode()` returns a `HexCode | undefined`.  Or even `isHexCode(str: string): str is HexCode` type guard.

Comment: Yeah @jcalz definitely any of those are important i thought i'd leave it up to him, definitely depends on the use-case because even just returning a default can work in alot of use-cases (I.E How games make missing textures default purple or a color that stands out so they can see its missing rather than throw)

Comment: `type HexCode = Opaque<string, "HexCode">`? Did you mean `type HexCode = Opaque<"HexCode", string>` instead?