# Is it possible to annotate alphabet-only string in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make type-annotation like this?

```js
name: OnlyAlfabetChars
```

where

```js
name = "someAlfabetChars"
```

is allowed but

```js
name = "some alpfabet"
```

or

```js
name = "123"
```

is not allowed.

Comment: There is no specific type like this in TypeScript.  You can use a *generic* type as a constraint and use a helper function, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXqL9N).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Also, does "alphabet" mean just upper and lower A-Z, or does it include other character sets?  Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply.

Comment: I'm still wondering: does "alphabet" mean just upper and lower A-Z, or does it include other character sets?  Should `"κάποιοαλφάβητο"` be accepted?  Should `"какойтоалфавит"` be accepted? Should `"いくつかのアルファベット"` be accepted? The first two are easy because those character sets make a distinction between uppercase and lowercase; the last one is hard. I can write up my answer but I hope you'll answer my question first

Comment: Looks a lot like [TypeScript type string of specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56720355/215552) or [Typescript - type to check if the string contains only specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72922880/215552)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript that acts this way.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) for *regular-expression validated string types* that would probably give you this, but for now this is not implemented.

The closest you can get to this is to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that acts as a constraint on a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), so that `T extends OnlyAlphabet<T>` if and only if `T` is a string literal type composed only of alphabetic characters.  And that means you would need a generic helper function to infer the generic type argument, so instead of `const x: OnlyAphabet = "abcdef";` you'd have to write `const x = onlyAlphabet("abcdef")`.

So, how can we implement `OnlyAlphabet<T>`?  We need to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to inspect the characters that make up a string, and in order to iterate over these characters we have to write it as a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).  Here's one approach:

```
type OnlyAlphabet<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
  OnlyAlphabet<R, `${A}${Uppercase<F> extends Lowercase<F> ? "A" : F}`> :
  A;

const onlyAlphabet = <T extends string>(
  x: T extends OnlyAlphabet<T> ? T : OnlyAlphabet<T>
) => x;
```

So `OnlyAphabet` is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) which checks each character in the input string.  If it's an alphabetical character it leaves it alone; otherwise it replaces it with a capital A.  So `OnlyAlphabet<"abcdef">` is just `"abcdef"`, but `OnlyAlphabet<"abcd3f">` is `"abcdAf"`.

Note that I take the shortcut that a character is alphabetical if and only if `Uppercase<F> extends Lowercase<F>` is false, using the intrinsic [`Uppercase<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype) and the [`Lowercase<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#lowercasestringtype).  This isn't perfect, but it works for a lot of character sets for which every alphabetical character has a distinct upper and lower case version, while non-alphabetical characters do not.  If you have some other idea of what makes a character "alphabetical" and it can be implemented in TypeScript's type system, feel free to change it.

The `onlyAlphabet` helper function is generic in `T` that's [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string`.  I would love to write `<T extends OnlyAlphabet<T>>(x: T)=>x`, but that's an illegally circular constraint.  Instead I use a quirk of inference and write `<T extends string>(x: T extends OnlyAlphabet<T> ? T : OnlyAlphabet<T>)=>x`.  When you call it, the compiler will infer `T` to be the type of the `x` input, and then it will check `T extends OnlyAlphabet<T>`.  If it succeeds, then the call succeeds because it amounts to `<T extends string>(x: T)=>x` which will work.  If it fails, then the call fails, because it amounts to `<T extends string>(x: OnlyAlphabet<T>) => x` which will not match.

---

Let's test it out:

```
let x = onlyAlphabet("someAlphabetChars"); // okay
let y = onlyAlphabet("some alphabet"); // error!
// Argument of type '"some alphabet"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"someAalphabet"'
let z = onlyAlphabet("123"); // error!
// Argument of type '"123"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"AAA"'
```

Looks good.  The compiler accepts a purely alphabetic string, but rejects ones with non-alphabetic characters and complains that the non-alpha character is not the letter A (so `"some alphabet"` is not `"someAalphabet"` and thus rejected).

In case it matters, this also works for other character sets that have distinct upper/lower case:

```
let w = onlyAlphabet("κάποιοαλφάβητο"); // okay
let v = onlyAlphabet("какойтоалфавит"); // okay
```

But fails for character sets with no such distinction:

```
let u = onlyAlphabet("いくつかのアルファベット"); // error!
// Argument of type '"いくつかのアルファベット"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"AAAAAAAAAAAA"'
```

So be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxAQQWAFgQwEYWAHgBUoIAPYCOAEwGcobgAnASzgHMAaKZE8y2+k1ZsoAXigAiCQD4xAWABQUKMTIVqdAAYASAN6sAZhEZQAYgF89h41ABK5zVAD8i5fCSoMOPPltcdusiWugCqYJCMAMaYNBD4prJq-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)

Comment: > "you would need a generic helper function to infer the generic type argument"


So currently it isn't possible to create a variable/constant that would enforce only letters, for example like this:
```TypeScript
const valid: OnlyLetters = "someAlphabetChars";
const invalid: OnlyLetters = "some AlphabetChars";
```
?

Comment: Right, that's what I was trying to convey with the opening sentence: "There is no specific type in TypeScript that acts this way."